# opening file from R.raw folder

Tags: java, android, inputstream, hashset, getresource

I am trying to open the file from my R.raw folder using inputstream. But I always got this error:

```
'The method getResources() is undefined for the type Wordchecker'
```

and when I tried to use quick fix another error appears.like this one:

```
'The method openRawResource(int) is undefined for the type Object'...
```

Here's my code:

```
public class Wordchecker {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        HashSet <String> newset = new HashSet <String>();
        try{
            //opening file of words
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wordlist);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
            String strLine;

            //reading file of words
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {  
                newset.add(strLine);  //adding word to the hash set newset
            }
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Object getResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you don't extend Activity. You cannot call `getResources()` because it doesn't exist

Without the Activity class you cannot use getResources() until you passe a context as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) somewhere, as [getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) is a method in Context.

Take an instance of it in your constructor:

```
public class Wordchecker {
    Context mContext;

    public Wordchecker(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        init()
    }

    public void init() {
        HashSet <String> newset = new HashSet <String>();
        try{
            //opening file of words
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wordlist);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
            String strLine;
            //reading file of words
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {  
                newset.add(strLine);  //adding word to the hash set newset
            }
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then create an object of this class from an Activity or Service or anything that extends Context using:

```
Wordchecker wordchecker = new Wordchecker(this);
```

Make sure the `wordchecker = new Wordchecker(this);` is in `onCreate()` or after

Comment: thank you for the help.,but when I am calling the newset, there is an error..I just wanted to check if my entered word's contained in my hashset(newset)..thanks..@Raghav Sood